# Using scikit-learn (sklearn), how to handle missing data (dependent var y) for linear regression?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

[image: here is the data table]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Data-hw1.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values #get a copy of dataset exclude last column
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values #get array of dataset in last column

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean') # taking care missing data
imputer.fit(x[:,1:3])

x[:,1:3] = imputer.transform(x[:,1:3])
print(x)
print(y)
```

[image: print (x)]

[image: print (y)]

My question is how to replace missing data in y to mean values in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# median
dataframe['column'] = dataframe['column'].fillna(dataframe['column'].median())

# mean
dataframe['column'] = dataframe['column'].fillna(dataframe['column'].mean())
```

Comment: I recommend you look for NaN values using seaborn